# Django's management_form not getting post data

Tags: django, django-forms, formsets

I'm having a trouble with django's formsets, the data from POST was being stored when I had just one formset but after I added a second one I am getting just the last input of each formset. 
Here are the forms:

```
class OperationsForm( forms.Form ):
    operation = forms.CharField(
        required = True,
        max_length = 20,
        widget = forms.TextInput( attrs = {
            'placeholder':'Operation Name'
            } ),
    )
class DataTypesForm( forms.Form ):
field = forms.CharField(
        required = True,
        max_length = 20,
        widget = forms.TextInput( attrs = {
            'placeholder':'Field Name'
        } ),
)
type = forms.CharField(
        required = True,
        max_length = 20,
        widget = forms.TextInput( attrs = {
            'placeholder':'Field Type'
        } ),
)
```

Here is the views.py:

```
    def index( request ):
     OperationsFormSet = formset_factory( OperationsForm )
     DataTypesFormSet = formset_factory( DataTypesForm )

if request.method == 'POST':
    operations_formset = OperationsFormSet( request.POST, prefix='operations' )
    data_formset = DataTypesFormSet( request.POST, prefix='datas' )

    if operations_formset.is_valid() and data_formset.is_valid():
        operations_list = []

        for operation_form in operations_formset:
            operation = operation_form.cleaned_data.get( 'operation'
            if operation:
                print( operation )
                operations_list.append( operation )
        operations = ' '.join(operations_list)
        operations = "\"" + operations + "\""

        data_list = []

        for data in data_formset:
            dataName = data.cleaned_data.get( 'field' )
            dataType = data.cleaned_data.get( 'type' )
            if dataType and dataName:
                dataToAdd = dataName + '-' + dataType
                data_list.append( dataToAdd )
        datas = ' '.join( data_list )
        datas = "\"" + datas + "\""

        print( "%s" % operations )
        print( "%s" % datas )
        #Do Something 
        return response
else:
    operations_formset = OperationsFormSet( prefix='operations' )
    data_formset = DataTypesFormSet( prefix='datas' )

context = { 'operations_formset': operations_formset, 'data_formset': data_formset }

return render( request, 'arquetipo/index.html', context )
```

Here is the index.html

```
    <div class="maven-arguments">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="operations">
                {% for f_form in operations_formset %}
                    <div class="operation-formset">
                        {{ f_form.as_table }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {{ operations_formset.management_form }}
            </div>

            <div class="data">
                {% for d_form in data_formset %}
                    <div class="data-formset">
                        {{ d_form.as_table }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {{ data_formset.management_form }}
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</br>
    <button types='submit' value='generate'>Generar</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that I use a JS to add or remove extra fields at runtime this is the code:

```
    <script>
       $('.operation-formset').formset({
        addText: 'Add operation',
        deleteText: 'Delete'
    });
       $('.data-formset').formset({
        addText: 'Add a field',
        deleteText: 'Delete'
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit more of your error? I'm understanding that your view works with one formset but not with two, right?

Comment: Exactly, when I had just the operations formset all the textfields values where passed to the list, if I add the other one just the last value of each one passes.

Comment: can you check if `request.POST` contains all data that you are expecting? I guess that only one form is being submited.

Comment: I've just found the solution and it was to 
    add prefix={prefix-name} 
on each js function, thanks for your help anyways